# Pandas Dataframe Data Type Conversion or Isomap Transformation

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I load images with scipy's misc.imread, which returns in my case 2304x3 ndarray. Later, I append this array to the list and convert it to a DataFrame. The purpose of doing so is to later apply Isomap transform on the DataFrame. My data frame is 84 rows/samples (images in the folder) and 2304 features each feature is array/list of 3 elements. When I try using Isomap transform I get error:

```
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

I think error is there because elements of my data frame are of the object type. First I tried using a conversion to_numeric on each column, but got an error, then I wrote a loop to convert each element to numeric. The results I get are still of the object type. Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
from scipy import misc
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import glob
from sklearn import manifold

samples = []
path = 'Datasets/ALOI/32/*.png'
files = glob.glob(path)
for name in files:
    img = misc.imread(name)
    img = img[::2, ::2]
    x = (img/255.0).reshape(-1,3)
    samples.append(x)

df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(samples, coerce_float = True)

for i in range(0,2304):
    for j in range(0,84):
        df[i][j] = pd.to_numeric(df[i][j], errors = 'coerce')
    df[i] = pd.to_numeric(df[i], errors = 'coerce')


print df[2303][83]
print df[2303].dtype
print df[2303][83].dtype

#iso = manifold.Isomap(n_neighbors=6, n_components=3)
#iso.fit(df) 
#manifold = iso.transform(df)
#print manifold.shape
```

Last four lines commented out because they give an error. The output I get is:

```
[ 0.05098039  0.05098039  0.05098039]
object
float64
```

As you can see each element of DataFrame is of the type *float64* but whole column is an *object*.

Does anyone know how to convert whole data frame to numeric?

Is there another way of applying Isomap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to reshape your image to a new shape instead of the original one?

If that is not the case then you should change the following line in your code

```
x = (img/255.0).reshape(-1,3)
```

with

```
x = (img/255.0).reshape(-1)
```

Hope this will resolve your issue